# Context menu entries in Windows

Tags: windows, contextmenu

Im looking for a way to have the context menu with more options, like copying text and sending it to a server, or translator. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Edit: Right clicking a string, which will allow me to parse that string into an aplication of mine. (So in Win Explorer).

Comment: Context menu where? In your application? In Explorer? And "on" what? A file? Text?

Comment: Are you trying to write a shell extension?

Comment: "Win Explorer" does not really have strings, are you talking about the list of files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See MSDN for information about [adding file type handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144146)

You basically have two options; you can register a simple static verb that executes a application (and passing the filename as a parameter), or you can create a shell extension that implements IContextMenu.

MSDN has [information about both methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171) (If you want to handle any file type, register yourself under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*` or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects`)